# Appwrite environment variables ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, appwrite

I'm using Appwrite on AWS (started with the pre-canned Appwrite marketplace and upgraded to 0.14.2.305).
In order to allow certificate generation, I need to update _APP_DOMAIN and _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET. however, no matter which value I put there, it is not "ingested" by the app (container restart and reboot of the server did not make any difference)
I also tried to read the values from the docker instance itself - but again - no value was read.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the Docker containers :)

Just run a `docker compose up -d` in your appwrite directory.